# Featuring questions that never got an answer or upvoted answer

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I think as we are reaching close to 4000 questions that do not have an answer or an upvoted answer, would it be possible to feature perhaps every day an older question (in a feature box that remains at the top) that never received an answer or an upvoted answer?

Comment: Doesn't this already exist? The community user bumps old unanswered questions regularly.

Comment: @doubleAA: Yes, however I think it should remain at the top for the entire day in a featured box.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/dealing-with-old-questions

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way to make this happen would be to [offer a bounty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on an old question that is unanswered and that you think should be answerable. Then, that question will be listed under the "Featured" tab for seven days or until you award the bounty to a worthy answer, whichever comes first. It'll also get bounced to the home page, and I think automatically tweeted about.

Comment: But that does take a reputation hit.

Comment: @Ploni Think of it as an investment, not a hit.