# Second Mi Yodeya Answerathon!

Tags: discussion, answerathon

<sup>For those who missed it: This program was first proposed [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/); the first round took place [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/); and the changes to the competition for this round were discussed [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4926/).</sup>

---

Welcome to the second Mi Yodeya answerathon! If you're new here, welcome, and if this is your second round, make sure to stick around, as some of the rules have changed since last time.

The goal here is to answer as many *unanswered* (i.e., no non-negative answers nor accepted ones), *open, non-negative* questions as possible (with a cut-off that all eligible questions are at least 30 days old), *and get your answers upvoted* (i.e. at least a net +2; in other words, all answers netting a Revival badge for previously unanswered questions).

Among the changes this time, there will be two simultaneous programs going on. Both will begin on **Monday, November 4, first day of Bahab.**

Have fun!

---

## Main Answerathon

Once the contest starts, you must post every day<sup>1</sup> and get two upvotes within 24 hours of posting to remain in the contest.<sup>2</sup> Once all but one person is knocked out, the contest is over!

What’s the prize for playing, you ask? Potentially, thousands of reputation points, from 20 points for every eligible answer, plus submissions to our preexisting [Best Answer Contest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/).<sup>3</sup>

How do you play? All you have to do is find a question [from **this list**](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/revision/1121195/1382098/)<sup>4</sup> and post an answer.<sup>5</sup> The more questions you answer, the better your chances of staying in (and the better your chances of gaining rep). Note that, due to the change in definition of "unanswered" for this round, if someone posts an answer to an eligible question and gets downvoted, *that question remains eligible for someone else to answer*.

There will be an answer below titled "Main Answerathon." When you've posted a qualifying answer, edit that answer to include your name and one of your qualifying answers in the section with the current date. If such a section doesn't exist yet, add it yourself to the bottom of the post using `##[Current Date]`.

As mentioned above, you must answer daily and receive two upvotes within 24 hours of posting to remain in the competition. Last user standing wins!

---

## Public Answerathon

Starting this round, we will have a Public Answerathon. What this means is that even if you're not in the Main Answerathon, you'll be able to submit answers to qualifying questions without having to worry about upvotes or posting every day. This will be less a competition and more a community project.

*Anyone*, whether in the Main Answerathon or not, who posts *any answer* on *any qualifying question* (as defined in the Main Answerathon section) should include *just the link* in the answer below entitled "Public Answerathon." I will do a sweep of this post once a week, B"N, and remove links to deleted answers; at the end of the competition, I'll remove links to downvoted answers as well. You can remove your own links if you want to, but it's not necessary.

Note that all prizes for playing in the Main Answerathon apply here as well!

When the Main Answerathon is over, the Public Answerathon will continue until the beginning of the first subsequent Shabbos. At that point we'll do a tally and see how many questions we've been able to sufficiently put to rest.

---

## Terms and Conditions

<sup>1</sup> "Day" starts and ends at midnight UTC.

<sup>2</sup>Friday and Shabbos count as one day; all answers posted on Friday get 48 hours as a result.

<sup>3</sup>What's the prize for *winning*? Uh, um, uh, bragging rights?

<sup>4</sup>Note that this list, being from SEDE, is only updated once a week, on Sundays. You might find questions there which are no longer valid, as well as questions which were not yet valid on Sunday which are currently valid. For a more limited subset of questions which is updated every fifteen minutes, try [this search query](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+is%3Aquestion+score%3A0..+created%3A..30d). Also try [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/revision/1121201/1382092/), which will try to filter the eligible questions by what's interesting to you, based on your top answered tags.

<sup>5</sup>Self-answering *is* allowed, so long as the question is on this list.

Comment: I found participation in the first round of this contest taxing, but even more rewarding. In my hunt for questions to answer, I first found many that I could answer by consulting one of my favorite sources. But then, I found many that had hints at answers suggested in comments but never realized; answering those pushed me to learn sources and think about topics that I rarely do otherwise, which was even more rewarding. Doing the farming necessary to convert such seeds into full-grown answers led to some of the answers on Mi Yodeya I'm most proud of.

Comment: @DonielF good initiative. Potentially you might have asked when is the best time to start this. I would be worried of competing with the Mishna siyum. We might have discussed and decided to postpone until after the siyum. Unless people feel one doesn't compete with the other. On my side, I won't be able to participate because of too many other commitments/work. But I loved it the first time around

Comment: @mbloch https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/ If enough people share this concern I’d be fine pushing it off a few weeks, but at the moment I’m keeping with what we decided last time to be the schedule moving forward. Let me ask on the chat also.

Comment: @DonielF makes sense

Comment: In order to fit in the “public answerathon” half, how many upvotes does the answer need?

Comment: @Loani I realize now I didn’t make that very clear. The threshold there is much lower: so long as it’s not downvoted. Doesn’t actually need any upvotes. Like I said, go ahead and add your answer to the list, and every so often I’ll do housekeeping on it.

Comment: So, what changed this time? Last time around there were tons of participants on day one. This time we have three.

Comment: @DonielF I would say: 1. Most of the “easy” questions were answered last time. 2. The novelty wore off. 3. It’s harder to qualify. 4. People can still qualify, don’t forget- they have until 24 hours after they posted there answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Public Answerathon

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109438/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109443/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109435/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109427/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109465/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109461/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109500/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109447/
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109540/

Answer (score 1):

## Main Answerathon

### Monday, November 4

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109438/ - DonielF
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109443/ - Isaac Moses
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109435/ - LoAni
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109447 - Alex

### Tuesday, November 5

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109465/ - LoAni

Comment: Is that it? We’ve only lasted two days?